# icalendar - date update does not work correctly in outlook

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar

I'm using icalendar to create a meeting. Once I create the meeting, it is sent correctly to my mail in outlook.

Then I update the meeting with start time and end time and I get it correctly in my mail - as an update meeting. I accept the meeting and view it in the calendar. I see the meeting in the calendar weekly view and it is updated with the correct time.

**But** once I open the meeting, the end time appears incorrect (it appears with duration of the original meeting).

For example:

```
meeting created 10:00AM-11:00AM (duration 1 hour)  
meeting updated 10:10AM-11:20AM (duration 1 hour 10 min)
```

Once I open the meeting, I see:

```
10:10AM-11:10AM (duration 1 hour)
```

The following is the ical creation of the meeting:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//dev//dev 1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150910T105742Z
DTSTART:20150922T070000Z
DTEND:20150922T080000Z
SUMMARY: 10092 : Tali new 11
UID:Change10092
CREATED:20150910T064456Z
SEQUENCE:0
CATEGORIES:aaaa
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<div>10092 : Tali new 11</div>
DESCRIPTION: 10092 : Tali new 11
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=FALSE;CN="devUser2, devUser2":mailto:talial@dev.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:none_noreply@dev.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And this is the ical of the meeting update:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//dev//dev 1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20150910T110143Z
DTSTART:20150922T071000Z
DTEND:20150922T082000Z
SUMMARY: 10092 : Tali new 11
UID:Change10092
CREATED:20150910T064456Z
SEQUENCE:1
CATEGORIES:aaaa
PRIORITY:5
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<div>10092 : Tali new 11</div>
DESCRIPTION: 10092 : Tali new 11
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=FALSE;CN="devUser2, devUser2":mailto:talial@dev.com
ORGANIZER:mailto:none_noreply@dev.com
STATUS:CONFIRMED
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Outlook displays the meeting with the correct dates on the weekly view and also in the tooltip of the view. It's only when I open the meeting that I see the end time is incorrect.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: outlook displays the meeting with the correct dates on the weekly view also in the tooltip of the view.
only when I open the meeting i see that the end time is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing wrong with your data from an iCalendar specification perspective as far as I can see.
To double check, you may want to try to import this event using another client (e.g. Thunderbird + Lightning) or send it to a cloud email + calendar service (google, hotmail, yahoo,...) and see how it is shown but it looks to me like it is more of an Outlook bug.

Comment: Thanks ! I've tried it in gmail and it's working well.